# How to include folder structure with symbols '+' & '-" indicating expansion & compression?

Tags: extjs

How to include folder structure with symbols '+' & '-" indicating expansion & compression respectively ? below code forms the tree with text as link but i want the link for folder pictures ?

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());

var children = [{ 
    text:'First Child',
    children: [{ 
        text:'First Child Level1',
        children: [{ 
            text:'First Child Level11',
            leaf:true 
        },{ 
            text:'First Child Level12',
            leaf:true 
        },{ 
            text:'First Child Level13',
            leaf:true 
        }] 
    }, {
        text:'Second Child',
        children: [{ 
            text:'Second Child Level1',
            leaf:true 
        },{ 
            text:'Second Child Level2',
            leaf:true 
        },{ 
            text:'Second Child Level3',
            leaf:true 
        }]
    }]
    }, { 
        text:'Third Child',
        children: [{ 
            text:'Third Child Level1',
            leaf:true 
        },{ 
            text:'Third Child Level2',
            leaf:true 
        },{ 
            text:'Third Child Level3',
            leaf:true 
        }] 
    },{
        text:'Fourth Child',
        children: [{ 
            text:'Fourth Child Level1',
            leaf:true 
    },{ 
        text:'Fourth Child Level2',
        leaf:true 
    },{ 
        text:'Fourth Child Level3',
        leaf:true 
    }] 
}];

Ext.onReady(function(){
    var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
        loader:new Ext.tree.TreeLoader(),
        width:1000,
        height:1000,
        renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
        root:new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
            expanded:true,
            leaf:false,
            text:'FAMILY',
            children:children
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can be done with literal text, but if you are able to use icons for '+' and '-', all that you need to do is set css, such as the following in your stylesheet:

```
.x-tree-node-collapsed .x-tree-node-icon {
    background-image: url(path/to/icon/plus.gif);
}

.x-tree-node-expanded .x-tree-node-icon {
    background-image: url(path/to/icon/minus.gif);
}
```

Which will replace the folder icons with plus / minus icons. There is an example of this on the [Sencha ExtJS Examples Site](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/two-trees.html)